# Set a cookie on using wp_login() hook

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, wordpress-theming

Im trying to set a cookie when my user logs into WP.

Im using the wp_login hook like so:

```
add_action('wp_login', array($this, 'knp_aci_login_check'), 1, 2);
```

And my cookie function:

```
public function knp_aci_login_check( $user_login, $user ) {
    $contact = $this->request->api_connect('contacts?filters[email]='.$user_login, 'GET');

    if (wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $contact ) == 200) {
        setcookie('ac-status', 'true', 365 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, '/', get_site_url());
    }
}
```

My cookie, just never saves.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the cookie without the condition?  Maybe it's not the setcookie, but that if statement is returning false.

Comment: By the looks of things it could be down to my timing. Aparantly you have to set the cookie during the init action. So may have to look at using php sessions isntead. Will update this post if I find the answer though.